# Game Center leaderboards in spritekit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, game-center

I'm trying to present my leaderboards from my main menu class but I'm getting some errors. Here's my code,

```
- (void) showLeaderboard
{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
}
}
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewControl*)viewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And i am getting 'no interface declares presentModalViewController:animated' 'no interface declares dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:. Can someone show me the right way to do this, i don't have much experience with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the present/dismiss view controller methods exist on view controllers and their subclasses and you're trying to call them with a subclass of SKNode as the receiver. In order to fix this, you need to get a reference to a view controller subclass and send these messages to it. The easiest way is probably via the node's scene's view's window's root view controller.

```
- (void) showLeaderboard
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self.scene.view.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
    }
}
- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewControl*)viewController
{
    [self.scene.view.window.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```